# ًWhy we use fourier transform in most of spectrum estimation approaches?

Tags: power-spectral-density, fourier, spectral-efficiency

I wonder why in all spectrum estimation techniques, the analysis depend on the Fourier transform? Why not deal with the signals in time domain?

Comment: By definition, a spectrum is a view of a signal in the frequency domain. The Fourier transform maps a time-domain signal to its equivalent in the frequency domain. It's a natural tool for many spectrum estimation problems.

Comment: Frequency is the characteristic of a source which is producing the signal.So if we record a complex signal which is due to the effect of 3-4 sources viewing it frequency domain allows us to separate the effect and view the signal as superposition of these individual signals.